# Problems matching caret in Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regular expression, which I think should match any character that is not alphanumeric, '!', '?', or '.'

```
re.compile('[^A-z ?!.]')
```

However, I get the following weird result in iPython:

```
In [21]: re.sub(a, ' ', 'Hey !$%^&*.#$%^&.')
Out[21]: 'Hey !  ^  .   ^ .'
```

The result is the same when I escape the '.' in the regular expression.

How do I match the caret so that it is removed from the string as well?

Comment: You say "alphanumeric" but your regex (despite it's flaws) only looks for letters.  Make sure it's what you want.

Comment: You're right - my mistake: when I said 'alphanumeric', I really meant the letters A-Z,.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your regular expression. Note that the case of the `a` and `z` is important. `A-z` includes all characters between ASCII value 65 (A) and 122 (Z), which includes the caret character (ASCII code 94).

Try this instead:

```
re.compile('[^A-Za-z ?!.]')
```

Example:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('[^A-Za-z ?!.]')
result = regex.sub(' ', 'Hey !$%^&*.#$%^&.')
print result
```

Result:

```
Hey !     .     .
```

Answer (score 0):

The caret falls between the upper and lower cases in ASCII. You need `[^a-zA-Z ?!\.]`